# JSF two beans and just one view?

Tags: jsf, inheritance, view, el, managed-bean

i have got following:

```
public abstract class aBean{... methods and variables ...}

@ManagedBean, ViewScoped
public class BeanType1 extends aBean{...only one method overritten...}

@ManagedBean, ViewScoped
public class BeanType2 extends aBean{...only one method overritten...}
```

is it possible to link to View.xhtml (h:outputlink) with BeanType1 and another link to (the same) View.xhtml with BeanType2? i need a kind of view-inheritance; like to use an EL-Expression like #{BEANPARAM.method} where BEANPARAM can be BeanType1 or BeanType2...

the view is exactly the same, and i want to avoid duplicating it...

is this possible or do I need two identival views with different beans (with #{viewScope[PARAM].}?
what i don't want is to use a GET-parameter, because the users can change this and this would result to different outcomes (insecurity)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have any kind of view-inheritance, but what you can do is re-use your view.

Write it dynamically using something like `#{beanParam....}` just like you already wrote yourself.

Then include your dynamic view with `<ui:include>` and define the beanParam with an `<ui:param>` like this:

```
<ui:include src="dynamicView.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="beanParam" value="#{beanType1}" />
</ui:include>
```